# how to access the azure table storage using UWP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, uwp, azure-table-storage

How to access the azure table storage data using Universal Windows. I want to connect the azure table storage in the visual studio 2015 Core. The Azure Storage Service not showing the connected service page.

Comment: Did you tried anything from your side till now?

Comment: Are you able to consume Azure Storage services in your UWP project now? If the reply could help you fix the issue, please mark it as an accepted answer to help other community members quickly find the answer to fix the similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

> The Azure Storage Service not showing the connected service page.

Firstly, please try to search and add **Microsoft Azure storage Connected Service**, like this.

[image]

[image]

Secondly, if you’d like to configure your project to consume Azure Storage services, you could also manually install [Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/).

[image]